# Should I use a slice or an iterator as a function argument?

Tags: rust, collections

What are the best practices in Rust, should I require a **slice** **or** an **iterator** as a function argument if de-facto either works right now?

Slice illustration:

```rust
fn my_function(elements: &[i32]) {
  for element in elements {
    do_something(element);
  }
}
fn main() {
  let my_vec = vec![1, 2, 3, ...];
  my_function(&my_vec);
}
```

Iterator illustration:

```rust
fn my_function(elements: impl IntoIterator<Item = impl Borrow<i32>>) {
    for e in elements {
        do_something(*e.borrow());
    }
}
fn main() {
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    my_function(&v);
}
```

Specifically, I would like to optimize for code that is easy to maintain and modify, when needed.

In other languages, some people advise to pick the [*least powerful and the most precise*](https://www.lihaoyi.com/post/StrategicScalaStylePrincipleofLeastPower.html#philosophy-principle-of-least-power) type possible when you're designing things.
In some other areas, especially frequently encountered in Java, it is common to require the [*most abstract*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java/util/Collection.html) type.

What is Rust's story? Any special considerations?
My general intuition would be to require slices, keep it simple, and change later if needed. If I understand it correctly, it might also be good for performance. Any other considerations?

Comment: It all depends on how you expect your consumers to call your functions. If you want to accept _any_ "collection" `impl IntoIterator` is probably a good idea.

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze the code in question is a binary, not a library, so all the caller's places are within the same crate. Currently, the de-facto callers have slices.

Comment: I don't think this is opinion based as there is an official recommendation.

Answer (score 5):

This is explicitly dealed with in the official [Rust API guidelines](https://rust-lang.github.io/api-guidelines/flexibility.html#functions-minimize-assumptions-about-parameters-by-using-generics-c-generic):

> ### Functions minimize assumptions about parameters by using generics (C-GENERIC)
>
> The fewer assumptions a function makes about its inputs, the more widely usable it becomes.
>
> Prefer
>
> ```rust
> fn foo<I: IntoIterator<Item = i64>>(iter: I) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> over any of
>
> ```rust
> fn foo(c: &[i64]) { /* ... */ }
> fn foo(c: &Vec<i64>) { /* ... */ }
> fn foo(c: &SomeOtherCollection<i64>) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> if the function only needs to iterate over the data.
>
> More generally, consider using generics to pinpoint the assumptions a function needs to make about its arguments.

There aren't any performance considerations, as generic functions will monomorphize and generic equivalent code to using slices. The code may be slower to compile, though.

However, this only deals with public functions. In private functions this is subjective. I prefer to take slices most of the time and change it only when needed, to avoid the compile-time cost and make the code shorter and clearer.